# how to edit dropdown field that lookup values from a table

Tags: php

I want to edit a dropdown field that lookup values from a table. normally, editing dropdown options in html we use something like:

```
<option value="montserrado" <?php if($ncounty == "montserrado") { echo "selected=\"selected\""; } ?>>Montserrado</option>
```

but once the dropdown list value is from a table, this method does not work for me.

Comment: What do you mean edit a dropdown? why would u do that? the point of dropdown is to select one or more elemenst from the provided list not to edit, rather user text input

Comment: you right, i want to be able to edit the value that was sent to the database

Comment: What database? You haven't mentioned any database.

Comment: Why do u think Select is the best option to edit a value?

Comment: <?Php
require "config1.php";  
 $sql="select * from plus2_country";
?>

Comment: this is the field:

Comment: <?php
          echo " <select class='form-control' id=department_code name=department onchange='depSelect(this);'><option value=''>Select department</option>";
          foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
          echo "<option value=$row[department_code] >$row[department]</option>";
           }?>
    </select>

Comment: sorry if i am not too clear, but basically what i want to do is to be able to edit the value that was sent to the database from this dropdown field. i don't know how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the drop down list programmatically would be the way to go.

Something like:

```
<?php 
$options = array('item1','item2','item3','etc');
$select = null; 
?>
<select name="field">
<?php
   foreach($options as $value) {
      if($value == "montserrado") {
          $select = " selected";
      } else $select = "";
      echo "<option$select>$value</option>";
 }
?>
</select>
```

If your fields are in a table then you will change your `$options` array would be generated with a call to your database.

For example using mysql and zend:

```
$dbcondetails = array('host' => 'dbhost', 'port' => '3306', 
     'dbname' => 'dbname', 'username' => 'user', password' => 'superpw');
$db = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_msyql', $dbcondetails);
$sql = 'select field from table';
$options = $db->fetchAll($sql);
```

This example ignore all the good error detection that can done with [php catch](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.catch.php), information on using the [Zend_db_Adapter](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.db.adapter.html) can be found [here](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.db.adapter.html).

You can edit the resulting `$_POST` data before you write it back to the database.

hth